# Question edit view displays same text for two edit descriptions

Tags: bug, editing

My edit's very atypical description exactly matches the one for @msell's edit.  Either his description matched mine exactly or automatically duplicated it, or the page is displaying my description twice when it should not.  Or other explanation.

[image]

Here's the page: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/posts/54555/revisions

Answer (score 1):

As best I can tell msell made an improve action on your edit rather than just approving it. That automatically copies the edit comment.

It is to avoid bumping the question multiple times, if a mini-mod during review find a small flaw in an otherwise good edit he can fix that flaw before approving, the result in the history looks like two edits at the same time.

Comment: I did notice that after a while, that a quick edit would copy the previous edit's description.  Mystery solved.